# Role based security asp.net mvc Trying to pass a Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to be clear, I had have trying almost that I can image.

My las shoot was something like.

```
[Authorize()]
[Secure(Roles = ActionRole.Admin.ToString())]
public class ActionController : Controller
{
    public enum ActionRole
    {
        Admin,
        Recruter,
        Sales,
        Developer
    }
}
```

And my original Idea.

```
[Authorize()]
[Secure(Roles = MyRoleClass.GetAuthorizedRolesForThisAction("ActionController"))]
public class ActionController : Controller
{
    //ActionController Related Code.
}

public Class MyRoleClass(){

    Public strgin GetAuthorizedRolesForThisAction(string Controller){
        //Accessing my DB and the searching is not the hard part here.
    }

}
```

I get this error.

```
Error   1   An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type
```

I'm trying to do this, because is not my Idea that every time that I have to change the Controller Roles Permission....  If any one have an Idea, will be appreciated.

Comment: Is secure a custom attribute? What does it look like?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do something like this with a custom `AuthorizeAttribute`. This adds a step that sets the Authorize attributes `Roles` before continuing with the `OnAuthorization` step.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class SecureAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) {
        var controller = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
        this.Roles = string.Join(",", MyRoleClass.GetAuthorizedRolesForThisAction(controller));

        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to just add the `Secure` attribute decoration:

```
[Secure]
public class ActionController : Controller
{
    //ActionController Related Code.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    [Authorize()]
    [Secure(Roles = "Contact/Index")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        //Get the user permissions from the Session. 
        //Using it every time that I get the controller and the action
    }
```

Hope this may help someone.
Thanks.